# Split url nsstring in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, ios7

If I have a Url as NSString like: 
    http://www.abarid.com/Mobile_apps/products_thumb/Untitled2.png

and I want to get only (Untitled2) as another NSString, how to do that in iPhone code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by looking at all of the path and URL related methods on `NSString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString* theExtractedName = [[yoururl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]
```

The `lastPathComponent` call will return "Untitled2.png", and the `stringByDeletingPathExtension` will remove the ".png"

Answer (score 0):

Use instance method `lastPathComponent`.